# How to Fetch Data using Date Condition in php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

Hello I am working with Word Press and I want to fetch records according to the the

date.MySQL database has a table `wp_evr_event` with  `end_date` column which has

a number of dates in **end_date column** according to each record like:

```
1. 2017-1-4
2. 2017-1-6
3. 2017-10-10
```

I want to fetch those record which has **End date**  greater than to the current

date.I used Query

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_evr_event` WHERE `end_date`>'2017-1-31'
```

But I get number of records which has the less date to the current date.

How to resolved this problem.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `wp_evr_event` WHERE DATE(`end_date`)>'2017-1-31'

Comment: @Anant Thanks it is working fine for me.

Comment: Shahzad Ditro  you are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DATE()` of mysql like below:-

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_evr_event` WHERE DATE(`end_date`)>'2017-1-31'
```

Note:- I think that end_date field is of `datetime` type , so that's why your code is not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `str_to_date` MySQL function to convert string into date. Here's the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_evr_event
WHERE str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2017-1-31';
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61ba65/2/0)**.